# Entity Reference Loop in large xhtml

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, notepad++

Im generating a large Xhtml file. When opening the file with notepad++, it says there is an Entity Reference Loop in my file.
The file is about 20K lines, and gives these errors on lines like:

```
<p class='tbl__description'>
&auml;rzaweqt;&auml;&ouml;&ocirc;
&eacute;&icirc;&Auml;&ecirc;&yuml;
&Ouml;&yen;&pound;&uacute; 
</p>
```

Does anyone know what this 'XML parsing error on line ... - Detected an Entity Reference Loop' means?
When the file is smaller, it does not seem to pop up... Only when it contains a lot of these Entity References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The &name; things are entity references.

XML (and thus XHTML with it) is too feature-full than is often good for you.

As shown in "[Is the Billion Laughs Attack supposed to be working in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992536/is-the-billion-laughs-attack-supposed-to-be-working-in-c)" you can define your own entities and reuse those in other entity-definitions. I guess the XML parser tries to detect these exploits and checks its memory usage when parsing entities. Your example is full of them, but I don't see a loop there.

Looks like [notepad++](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/tree/master/PowerEditor/src/TinyXml) uses TinyXml, perhaps you can spot where this error is raised.

On a sidenote: see [Tom Eastman - Serialization formats are not toys - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjZHjvrAS74) for some more examples of features in serialization formats that you may use to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: What would a loop look like? You'd create a custom entity reference that in turn references something else or what?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your document is saved in ansi encoding. You have to convert it in utf-8 to avoid this error. The named entities will be resolved to utf-8 characters according your entity definition. Some utf-8 characters must changed back to entities to save in ansi encoding. That's the forbidden loop!